# Adjectif sans nom à partir duquel le nom doit être inféré

Tags: usage, syntaxe

On trouve assez couramment par le passé et encore de nos jours ce qu'à première vue on pourrait appeler l'abréviation de « société générale de X » en « générale de X »  (par exemple « Générale de Chauffe »); probablement d'origine récente, les cas « les européennes », « les présidentielles », « les législatives » dont on doit entendre les formes comme signifiant  « les élections X » montrent qu'il doit exister une liste plus ou moins importante de ces noms avec lesquels l'''abréviation '' est permise.

- Quel serait le nom pour cette sorte de construction?
- Où trouver une liste de ces noms?
- Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait, à titre illustratif, dresser une liste plus ou moins étendue de noms importants de ce type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour ce qui est de la construction dans les cas du genre *élections législatives* → *législatives*, il s'agit sans le moindre doute d'une *substantivation par ellipse*.

Dans ce cas (ref le titre de la question), l'adjectif n'est pas du tout *sans nom*. L'adjectif n'est plus. C'est un nom à part entière.

Pour ce qui est des dénominations sociales, (noms propres) alors, par analogie avec l'étude de [Cusin-Berche](https://www.persee.fr/doc/linx_0246-8743_1992_num_27_2_1251) je ne parlerais effectivement plus de substantivation par ellipse ni d'*abréviation* mais bien plutôt de **caducité**. On a laissé tomber un (groupe de) mot(s) qui *tombent sous le sens* dans le contexte.

La liberté étant presque totale dans le domaine des dénominations sociales, le créateur fait... ce qu'il veut avec pour seul et unique impératif de rester signifiant pour sa clientèle. On peinera alors à répertorier les différentes occurrences.